# Why json download with Python urllib.request is so slow? How can I make it faster?

Tags: python, json, urllib

I perform the following code:

```
import urllib.request
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime.now()
user_agent = 'First Lastname abc@def.com' # SEC uses this format as header.

url = 'https://data.sec.gov/submissions/CIK0000320193.json'
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,} 

request=urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers) 
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
data = response.read()
print(datetime.now() - start)
```

It took me `0:02:33.646154` 2.5 minutes.
That doesn't make sense to me because I can open the link with browser in less than a second.
Why does the code so slow? How could I make it faster?
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Which *part* of this code is taking the most time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the exact code you provided and it returned in `0:00:00.515504` seconds.

Here are 3 reasons for why it might take *you* so long until it is returned.

1. Your computer is incredibly slow.
2. Your internet connection is slow/unstable.
3. Maybe `https://data.sec.gov` deliberatly takes so long to return to you because you ran the code a lot of times and is giving you some kind of cool-down.

Comment: Why wouldn't these all apply to opening the link in a browser?

Comment: Yeah you are right. I have rerun it and finished in 0:00:00.377205. Thank you for testing